# A question about Paraconsistent Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

In [question No.134351](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134351) it is asserted that there exists a Paraconsistent Set Theory in which the
Continuum Hypothesis (CH) is disproved. I would like to know more about this theory, which I will
call PST. Is it true that PST is formalizable in the language of first order ZF (even though its 
rules of inference and some of its logical axioms are different from those of ZF)? Is it also true 
that "not CH" is a theorem of PST but that "CH" is not a theory of PST?....If the answer to both
of these questions is "yes" (and if PST has no special "ad hoc" axioms designed to disprove CH),
then this seems to me to be a very noteworthy result which I had never heard about until now.

Comment: As an aside, I believe the paper in which PST is shown to have these properties is "Transfinite cardinals in paraconsistent set theory" by Zach Weber (http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=8559794), in the 2012 Review of Symbolic Logic. 

Comment: Thanks alot for this information. I will try to get hold of that
article and hope I will be able to understand it.

Comment: I am currently reading Weber's paper and the gist of his proof that not-CH holds is that |omega|<|P(omega)|<|P(omega)| holds in his system of paraconsistent set theory.

Comment: I was interested in this question too and found a PDF of the article on Weber’s website: https://sites.google.com/site/doctorzachweber/Publications.